# How to show progress bar while loading ListView?

Tags: android, listview, progress-bar

I'm loading ListView from Firebase database, and I want that while it loads the ListView, it will show a progress bar.

I've read some guides and I tried somethings but it doesn't work for me.

This is my code:

```
public class Event_List_Activity extends Activity {
private static final String FIREBASE_URL="https://****.firebaseio.com/";
private Firebase firebaseRef;
final ProgressBar pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_event__list_);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    firebaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

    //populateEventList();
    new MyTask().execute();

    final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            openEventInfo(parent,view,position,id);

    }
    });

}



class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String>
{

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String...strings)
{
    populateEventList();
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...values)
{
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    pb.setProgress(values[0]);

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s)
{
    super.onPostExecute(s);
}
}





private void populateEventList()
{
    firebaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {


            ArrayList<String> subTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<EventClass> eventList = new ArrayList<EventClass>();
            ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (DataSnapshot user : snapshot.child("users").getChildren()) {

                String event_title = user.child("event/event_title").getValue().toString();

                String event_date = user.child("event/event_date").getValue().toString();
                subTitles.add(event_date);
                String event_content = user.child("event/event_content").getValue().toString();
                String age_limit = user.child("event/age_limit").getValue().toString();
                String event_hour = user.child("event/event_hour").getValue().toString();
                String location_left = user.child("location_left").getValue().toString();
                String location_right = user.child("location_right").getValue().toString();

                EventClass oneEvent = new EventClass(event_title, event_date, event_content, age_limit, event_hour, location_left, location_right);
                eventList.add(oneEvent);

            }


            for (EventClass event : eventList) {
                titles.add(event.getEvent_title());
            }
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(Event_List_Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles) {

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                                    ViewGroup parent) {
                    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                    return view;
                }
            };
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            String message = "Error";
            Toast.makeText(Event_List_Activity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

private void openEventInfo(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    final String selectedTitle = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    firebaseRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot user : dataSnapshot.child("users").getChildren()) {
                String event_title = user.child("event/event_title").getValue().toString();
                if (selectedTitle.equals(event_title)) {

                    String event_date = user.child("event/event_date").getValue().toString();
                    String event_content = user.child("event/event_content").getValue().toString();
                    String age_limit = user.child("event/age_limit").getValue().toString();
                    String event_hour = user.child("event/event_hour").getValue().toString();
                    String location_left = user.child("location_left").getValue().toString();
                    String location_right = user.child("location_right").getValue().toString();
                    final SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("key", 0);
                    final SharedPreferences.Editor sedt = sp.edit();

                    sedt.putString("event_title", event_title);
                    sedt.putString("event_date", event_date);
                    sedt.putString("event_content", event_content);
                    sedt.putString("age_limit", age_limit);
                    sedt.putString("event_hour", event_hour);
                    sedt.putString("location_left", location_left);
                    sedt.putString("location_right", location_right);

                    sedt.commit();

                }

            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(Event_List_Activity.this, EventInfo.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(Event_List_Activity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}




}
```

After reading a comment, this is the change I've made in my `MyTask()` method:

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String>
{

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    super.onPreExecute();
    listView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String...strings)
{
    populateEventList();
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...values)
{
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    pb.setProgress(values[0]);
    pb.setMax(values[1]);


}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s)
{
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well `FireBase` has complete solution for every task. Here is how we are going to show progress while downloading or uploading things. As stated on [this blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/5-tips-for-firebase-storage.html), We can use inbuilt methods of `FireBase` API.

So first of all please remove all the AsyncTask code just to download and show progress. FireBase already works on other thread so there is no need of AsyncTask. So you have do something like this

```
StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference().child("folderName/file.jpg");
Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("path/to/images/file.jpg"));
UploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(file);
uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener() {
@Override
public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
    System.out.println(snapshot.getBytesTransferred().toString());
}
});
```

Let me know if it helped you.

Answer (score -1):

You have to manually call `publishProgress` in `doInBackground` somewhere 
[AsyncTask publishProgress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...))

EDIT:

Let me be a bit more specific...
If you want to only show a progress bar while your data is being loaded you ca do something like that.

In `onPreExecute` you could hide the `listView` and set the `visibility` of your `progressBar` to `VIEW.VISIBLE`.

Then in `doInBackground` each time you receive a new data set you call `publishProgress(current, max)` with maybe the current number of received data and the max amount.

Then in the `onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)` you set the new Max-Value by `pb.setMax(values[1])` and the actual value `pb.setProgress(values[0])`.

Once every dataset is loaded `onPostExecute()` will be called and you change the visibility of your `progressBar` back to `VIEW.GONE` and set the visibility of the `ListView` back to `VIEW.VISIBLE`.

Comment: Hi, firstly, thanks for the comment!
Secondly, I didn't understand what to do in the line you wrote `Then in doInBackground each time you receive a new data set you call publishProgress(current, max) with maybe the current number of received data and the max amount.` What is the current and what is the max? And what do you mean when you say every time I receive a new data set?

Comment: By the way, I've added the code changes above, to my question.

Comment: So i don't know anything about the Firebase Database. But since you have defined a `FIREBASE_URL` i assume you are receiving the data over internet. OK then -- In your `populateEventList` you are receiving data from the DB. Then i wanted to refresh the `progressBar` by using the current number of received Events (the ones that you acually have received in your `eventList`) and the maximum number of Events (could be something like `snapshot.child("users").getChildren().Lenght`) in the DB.

Comment: This question was asked for showing progress while using firebase for long running operations like downloading files or whatever. Firebase already works on different thread. So use of AsyncTask will not solve problem.